# CSS not being used by my view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in an Index.cshtml file:

```
    @{ViewBag.Title = "Home";}
<link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<img id="logo" src="~/Content/Images/Logo.png" />
```

This file is a view in my ASP.NET MVC4 application.

When I run the web application, I can see that the source code adds the appropriate HTML around this, and also adds a reference to the 'Content\Site.css' file.

However, neither the Site.css file nor my own Home.css CSS file appear to be used when running the application. First of all, any edits I make to Site.css aren't reflected when I view source when running the application, which is weird. I have saved everything and built the project before running it and checking out the source code through my browser.

Second of all, the CSS link to Home.css (which is in the same folder as my view) does not appear to be used. The HTML editor doesn't have a problem with the file, and so indicates that the path is valid - but when I click on Home.css in my the source code editor on my browser, I get a 404 error, saying that the file doesn't exist.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong here?

The actual image I am using here loads correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the CSS link to Home.css (which is in the same folder
>   as my view) does not appear to be used.

The `Views` folder is restricted direct access to from the clients. So you should not be putting any CSS, javascript or images files inside it. They should reside in your `~/Content` folder (or some other folder which is accessible from the clients). And then reference it like this:

```
<link href="~/Content/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

As far as your first problem about `~/Content/Site.css` is concerned, the stylesheet might be cached by the browser. Try clearing the cache. If you are running your application in Release mode and enabled Bundles, ASP.NET MVC 4 will automatically emit a cache response header so that the static resources included in the bundle get cached in the browser.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks. Perhaps I need to go back to the MVC tutorials.

Comment: the tilde doesn't make sense either - if you run the page in chrome, then inspect the DOM, can you click on the link to the stylesheet? If you can click on it and see the contents then it's being included. Try removing the tilde ~ or do a ../ or whatever to get to it

Comment: @DevinMcQueeney, it does make sense!!! Razor 2 (which is what ASP.NET MVC 4 uses) automatically converts it to the corresponding relative path. Please read here: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-the-new-tilde-slash-feature-in-razor-2 That's a new feature in ASP.NET MVC 4. In previous versions you would have used the corresponding helper but that's no longer necessary: `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Home.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Comment: I should note that is still appears to work fine without the tilde. Thanks for the contributions though.

Comment: No this doesn't work at all without the tilde! I mean it probably works when you are testing locally in Cassini but as soon as you deploy your application on IIS inside a virtual directory name your code will immediately break. So the tilde, as I've mentioned in my previous comment, is of an extreme importance and it should be there. Suppose you've deployed your application inside a virtual directory called `MyApp`. Then `~/Content/Home.css` will generate `/MyApp/Content/Home.css` which is the correct location. If you used `/Content/Home.css` you will get a 404 error as soon as you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

you also could use `@url.content()` helper method to convert your relative path to absolute. It's extremely useful when you will implementing website with multiple areas and also it's the common style to set path to the content in MVC so it's better does it this way

Answer (score 0):

css belongs in the head - i can't stand .net

It also needs to NOT have the closing /> at the end of the tag - it messes things up. XHTML proper, but not everyone understands it. Unclose the link tag and try...

Comment: It's The Visual Studio HTML editor which wants me to close it this way, so that doesn't seem quite right...

Answer (score 0):

Use `~/` before your file statement for example:

`<img src="~/images/team-image3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">`

instead of

`<img src="images/team-image3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">` etc...